# Making eaglecad library for ATSAMD21G: how to copy TQFP48 package to my new library

Tags: eaglecad

I did look in the standard library for Eaglecad, but I see no entry for the SAM D chips.

While searching, I saw posts that say to make my own, so I did.

Now, I have the schematic for the D21G, but I need the footprint. From my understanding, I can use another TQFP48 package from another chip and that should be OK.

Is this true or do I have to do from scratch also the packaging? I am not sure if I would be able to do that from scratch; the sparkfun tutorial was not really clear.

I wish there were libraries already made for the components that I need, but sadly they are not. Design with Eagle seems to put hurdles after hurdles, in front of the newbies :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the library you want to copy the package INTO is open. Browse in the control panel to the package you want to copy, right click it and select 'copy to library'. Then that package will be available in your library to connect up as a device variant.

Comment: Thanks; is this OK? I was wondering if copying another TQFP package would cause issues or if they are basically standard, like the stadard SMD component.

Comment: 90% of the time, yes, the footprint will probably match if they're using the same name for the package. But always always always check the datasheet against your library part. Sometimes they will be different. There is no standards police to enforce naming conventions (although there should be!)

Comment: Much appreciated, Dan! I was under the impression that footprint and packaging was standardized; but you just told me that they are not, so a TQFP from one manifacturer may vary from another TQFP from another. I was also suggested to print on paper first and try the real components on the paper mockup to be super sure that the pitch and size are exactly the same. Now I understand why it is so important.